# Active directory cannot install msi, reason: newer version is installed. But It has never been installed on target system

Tags: windows, active-directory, installation, windows-installer

I try install my .msi package with Active directory to clean Windows 8.1.
Cannot install to target system, sysytem log contains error:
“A Newer Version” is already installed
One important thing: that is clean system.
Registry don't contain "product code" or "upgrade code" of my software.
But if installing software manualy - it is installing correct.
Some other software installing correct(grepWin x64).

- msi unpacked from setup.exe - that was build by Installshield 2013
- active directory: windows server 2012
- target: Windows 8.1

Any suggestions to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You won't find ProductCodes or UpgradeCodes in the registry, so searching for them doesn't tell you anything. They are obfuscated. APIs like MsiEnumRelatedProducts (and equivalents) are more accurate.

The general problem may be that the particular ProductCode is already installed in some context that you may not be aware of (per user vs per machine). Strictly speaking, it's the combination of ProductCode and install context that means "already installed". Duplicate PackageCodes can also trigger this error, but that seems unlikely from what you've said.

It's also not clear if you are intending a fresh install or an upgrade of an existing product using major upgrade.

So if you can install it manually but not with AD, then check the context of the AD install and your manual one. If there is a per user install on the system and AD attempts to install another then you'll see this error. In AD, it's something like publishing to the user (per user) vs assigning to the machine (per machine). Vice versa too, you can install per user if there is already a per machine, but AD can't install another per machine if there is already one there. Note that if you're logged on as some other user it will complicate things. There may be a per user install under another account that AD is complaining about, while you and your account can install a per user or per machine.

Comment: 1) never setupped before - mean - never setuped before 2) i know about obfuscation - this situation cannot happend clean just installed windows can't contain my product/upgrade code.
About obfuscation:
before: 12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456789012
after: 87654321-dcab-dcab-bacd-214365780921

Comment: registry contains upgrade codes and product codes
if msiexec can't finde there - he think they don't exist

I know somthing wrong with AD or win8 machine or with msi
but i need some suggestions to looking what is wrong

i try at clean windows, virtual machines and different PC

Answer (score 0):

I found answer.
Sequences->Installation->Execute->ISPreventDowngrade.

Condition was strange, it was check for version and major upgrade.
When it setted to "ISFOUNDNEWERPRODUCTVERSION" installaition work fine with AD.

I still don't understand why installation doesn't work before with AD and work fine with normal (and silent mode) installation.